# USPS configuration isn't working

Tags: shipping, configuration, error, usps

I am setting up a Magento store on Community 1.9
I am trying to configure USPS shipping. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong - all I see when I do a test order is "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time."

I'm attaching a screenshot of my configuration. The only thing I'm not sure about it "Packages request type" (what does this mean???) but everything else should be all set...any ideas for why this isn't working?[image]

Comment: What do you see in your error logs? var/log/*

Answer (score 3):

Change the container to be regular. If this doesn't work then change test scope to develop and try again.

If all else fails then you need to inspect the logs on the filesystem. If Developer Logging is on then you will see a file under /var/export that is specific to USPS.  This will tell you the reason for failure.

99% of the time its an authorization issue.